# Inheriting default ComboBox to change border color or disable it

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, user-controls

I'm working in a WinForms project.

I have a dark theme activated in Windows and this is a default combobox when it's focused:

[image]

And this is when it has no focus:

[image]

An horrible and insane white border appears when the control lost focus, I want to avoid that without disabling XP Styles in the project.

I know that maybe the only way is inheriting the control to make my own, the problem is I don't know what I need to do with the control, maybe changing a setstyle property or I don't know.

Comment: I think thats just the WM_NCPAINT message?

Comment: @Sayse i have read a comment on another SO question saying this "The days of intercepting WM_NCPAINT to do it yourself are long gone, much too complicated to deal with the user's visual styles and glass preferences", anyways I don't know what I need to do when intercepted the message.

Comment: Ah right yeah that makes sense, (sorry I've been working in another language lately where thats the only way!) either way I believe that is part of the non client area, I'm just unfamiliar with how to work with it it seems...

Comment: @Mert yep in a machine using the default windows theme the control borders seems "normal" and maybe looks pretty, but if you are using a 3rd party theme then sure you will stop using control visual styles and to change the border color or disable it like me, thanks for comment!

Comment: I did some work on an inherited cbo some time ago and it is a PITA.  It does not act like an integral control but like the TextBox and  Button with soemthing like a context menu which it prolly is.  Have you tried the 5 cent solution of fiddling with BackColor in `Leave` and `Enter`.  The problem is picking the colors on systems with other schemes.  BTW it is odd looking, but more a function of the color scheme - just using dark colors doesnt result in that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you're trying to solve a problem that isn't in the scope of your application.  Isn't this just an issue with the theme in question you are using?

Windows has many themes.  The major themes still supported are Classic (pre-XP), Luna (XP), Aero (Vista/Win7), and Modern (Windows 8).  All of these can be customized to create an infinite number of possible scenarios.

Most Windows Forms controls are based on Win32 controls which are drawn by the OS according to these system themes.

So you have to understand that on the machine you're testing on what you're seeing is going to vary a lot from what users of the application will see on different versions of Windows with different user preferences.

The simple fact is that if you use WinForms base controls you really should surrender control of the appearance to the OS as much as possible.

It's also widely accepted to create your own application theme that the user can't change or that they have to pick from a predetermined set of themes you have created.  Examples of this include Google Chrome, iTunes, Winamp, etc.  It is typically an awful lot of work to do this with simple Win32 controls unless you use something like WPF which makes it easier.

The important thing is that you can't really pick and choose which parts of your application to theme.  If you want it to look consistent you either take responsibility for the entire theme yourself or follow the Windows standards of using system resource colors such as ControlText, ActiveBorder, AppWorkspace, etc.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but isn't not what I'm looking for, I need information or example to inherit my user control from a default Framework control only to disable the border or change the color, I know that is possibly 'cause you can see much user controls inherited from the default controls without that borders. When I develop an application and if I go to share it then I allways put a theme selector, one theme to use the Windows standards to turn all the control colors to the dafults using the "defaultcolor" property os the controls, and other theme to use nice colors for my Windows theme.

Comment: (sorry, too much characters, i follow my comment here) and so that's the reason why I want to disable the white border color or change the color to look pretty with my windows theme, I'm not asking for how to fully make an user control and fully customize it, I know that's really a hard work, I know the very basics of how to inherit a default control like overload or override their methods by my owns, I only need to know how to work the borders of the inherited control to look like I need. thanks for comment

Comment: In the case of a control like a ComboBox, you can't override certain functionality.  You can either paint the entire thing yourself, or let the OS paint it.  You can't pick and choose.

Comment: The only parameters that you can set which the OS may listen to are the ones defined on ComboBox and its ancestor classes.  Such as BackColor, ForeColor, DropDownStyle, Font, etc.  It doesn't let you hook into different parameters of its painting process because the painting process isn't the same for every Windows theme.